# Select the most recent distinct records of a two column pair

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Requirements:**

I need to select `[SKU]`, `[Store]`, `[Cost]`, and `[Retail]` for one of each distinct (`[SKU]`, `[Store]`) combination from `[PriceChanges]` where `[Date]` is the most recent (not exceeding 2017-04-25) and `[Flag]`=0. I also only want to select `[PriceChanges]` records where `[Dept]`=100 as determined by joining to `[Items]` via `[SKU]`.

Below are some obfuscated sample data from my tables, but in reality I expect to pull back about 2 million unique records in my result set.

**`[PriceChanges]` (Sample):**

```
+--------+-------+--------+--------+------------+------+
|  SKU   | Store |  Cost  | Retail |    Date    | Flag |
+--------+-------+--------+--------+------------+------+
| 999999 |  1000 | 4.0850 | 4.09   | 2017-04-19 | 0    |
| 999998 |  1001 | 4.0850 | 4.09   | 2017-04-19 | 1    |
| 999999 |  1000 | 4.0650 | 4.07   | 2017-04-18 | 2    |
+--------+-------+--------+--------+------------+------+
```

**`[Items]` (Sample):**

```
+--------+------+
|  SKU   | Dept |
+--------+------+
| 999999 |  100 |
| 999998 |  101 |
+--------+------+
```

**My Current Solution:**

```
SELECT s.[SKU],
     s.[Store],
     [Cost],
     [Retail]
FROM [PriceChanges]  s
    RIGHT JOIN
(
   SELECT [SKU],
        [Store],
        [MaxDate] = MAX([Date])
   FROM [PriceChanges]
       LEFT JOIN [Items] ON [PriceChanges].[SKU] = [Items].[SKU]
                                                 AND [Date] < '2017-04-25'
                                                 AND [Dept] = 100
                                                 AND [Flag] = 0
   GROUP BY [SKU],
          [Store]
) m ON m.[SKU] = s.[SKU]
     AND m.[Store] = s.[Store]
     AND m.[MaxDate] = s.[Date];
```

The solution above doesn't seem to work as it returns about 40% more records than I would expect based on the number of distinct SKUs and Stores we have. What is the most efficient way to write this query?

Comment: please post the desired result and also let us know which version of sql-server you are using.

Comment: Please update your question with the sample expected result based on your sample data. You might want to add some additional sample data to demonstrate some edge cases. For instance, is there ever a case where the same (SKU/Store) combo can have more than one row with Flag=0?

Comment: thanks, @vkp and @ pmbAustin . I'm on my way out the door, but will try to update with your suggestions in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT [SKU],
     [Store],
     [Cost],
     [Retail]
FROM
(
   SELECT [SKU],
        [Store],
        [Cost],
        [Retail],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [SKU],
                                 [Store] ORDER BY [Date] DESC) rn
   FROM PriceChanges PC
   WHERE [Date] <= '2017-04-25'
        AND [Flag] = 0
        AND EXISTS
   (
      SELECT [SKU]
      FROM [Items] i
      WHERE pc.[SKU] = i.[SKU]
           AND [DEPT] = 100
   )
) t4
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, @KumarHarsh . This looks like it work as well (looks very similar to Josh's answer).

Comment: No it is not similar.I am using "Exists" clause.Check for performance.

Comment: you are right. I saw approximately a 31% improvement in performance with your answer over Josh's. Your answer did have a couple typos in it, though. I just submitted an edit to fix them. I'll switch my accepted answer if that gets approved.

Answer (score 2):

If you definately only want one row returned by SKU and Store, you could use the following query:

```
SELECT
   [SKU]
  ,[Store]
  ,[Cost]
  ,[Retail]
FROM (
  SELECT
     p.[SKU]
    ,p.[Store]
    ,p.[Cost]
    ,p.[Retail]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.[SKU], p.[Store] ORDER BY p.[Date] DESC) as ranker
  FROM [PriceChanges] p
  JOIN [Items] i
    ON p.[SKU] = i.[SKU]
  WHERE 1=1
    AND i.[Dept] = 100
    AND p.[Flag] = 0
    AND p.[Date] < '2017-04-25'
) T
WHERE 1=1
  AND ranker = 1
```

Comment: Why the `WHERE 1=1`?

Comment: Ah this is just habbit. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54954/why-use-where-1-or-where-1-1

Comment: This one produced the exact number of records I was expecting. Thanks!